# ListView not utilizing full space in FrameLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, layout, android-framelayout

I have an activity layout with 2 FrameLayout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.sioned.multivoc.AddWordActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scLeft"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/paneLeft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/paneLeftTop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/paneLeftBottom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/paneLeftTop"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The 2nd FrameLayout paneLeftBottom will at some point contain the following fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...some static fields...
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lyTop">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this configuration the ListView is only shown with a height of one of it's rows instead several rows utilizing the available space. The ListView works fine but only one row at a time is displayed.

The same ListView fragment works fine when I put it into a 2-pane landscape layout. How can I make the ListView use the available space ?

Edit:

Found a partial solution by switching to a LinearLayout within the ScrollView. Only problem left is, that the bottom Framelayout overlays a bit of the top FrameLayout when I load the said fragment into it. But that is acceptable in this case as it is only temporary to select some data.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scLeft"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/paneLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/paneLeftTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/paneLeftBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why the height is `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: why are you matching the parent height, shouldent the height be wrapped?

Answer (score 0):

This right here

```
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Should be

```
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Match parent on height will take up the entire screen for a item

Comment: I assume you are talking of the layout_height of the 2nd FrameLayout. I tried wrap_content there and it makes no difference.

Comment: I just noticed, that the ListView will utilize more space when I set layout_height of the paneLeftBottom FrameLayout to a fixed height like 200dp. So I could probably solve this problem by setting the height programmatically to use the remainin space, but I would prefer a XML solution.